# Specify Solr request handler in query

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have created a new request handler in Solr name `mySearch`, in the older versions of Solr I can use the default select request and specify the custom request handler using the "qt" parameter. But in Solr 6.0 that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way I can invoke the new request handler using a query param instead of solr/mySearch?

Comment: have you tried with `SolrQuery().setRequestHandler("mySerach")`?

Comment: Could you post the `mySearch` request handler configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Solr 6, this is controlled by the parameter [handleSelect](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/6.0.0/solr/server/solr/configsets/basic_configs/conf/solrconfig.xml#L343-L357) which needs to be set to true and the solrconfig.xml should not have select handler (it does in all examples).

Once you fulfill both conditions, you should be able to get your old behavior to work.